# How can I make a proper request to a URL using async task and look for a specific element?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've recently used `AsyncTask` into my android app and what this piece of code is doing, is making a get request to the provided url, and retrieving the song name from it. (The URL is a Spotify song). When I print out the response I am getting, it says

```
com.(projectname).(projectname).TRetrieve$HttpGetRequest@aed19ea
```

(TRetrieve is the name of the class that is doing this request)

How can I make the request and properly get the name of the song back?

This is the code for the class so far:

```
public class HttpGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        String stringUrl = "https://open.spotify.com/track/5Q41NLTmGbVPozwHKK7bk2";
        String result;
        String inputLine;
        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                    myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            connection.connect();
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            result = stringBuilder.toString();

            linkLoc = result.indexOf(testString) + testString.length();
            for (int i = linkLoc; i < result.indexOf("on Spotify"); i++) {
                sname += result.charAt(i) + "";
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            sname = "Error";
        }

        return sname;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: That url opens the spotify login page in my browser.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Yes, from this login page, I am able to look through the response, and retrieve the song that is displayed on it.

Comment: You will need something like [`Jsoup`](https://jsoup.org/download) to parse the `html`.

Comment: @KNeerajLal will do. But what is the response that I am getting back? I have no idea what this get request from asynctask is returning

Comment: What is the result of `Log.e("data", result);` inside `doInBackground`?

Comment: @KNeerajLal it is just the response from the webpage. It does not do anything because the program does not go into the catch statement when run

Comment: So you are getting the response in `result`. So what is the issue?

Comment: When I print result, it is printing: com.(projectname).(projectname).TRetrieve$HttpGetRequest@aed19ea. Instead of a song name

Comment: By result do you mean `sname` or `result` variable?

Comment: @KNeerajLal sname

Comment: String songName = new HttpGetRequest().execute(params).get();

Comment: My Pleasure .. @Programmer87

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with API using `AsyncTask` / `HttpURLConnection` is very old-school. I suggest yo to use modern way to do it, using `RxJava` / `Retrofit` / `Gson`

## 1). Adding necessary dependencies

Add next dependencies to your `<root>/app/build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2')
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
```

## 2). Creating HTTP client

**2.1)*** *(This is optional, only if you need to send AUTH token in headers)*
Create interceptor:

```
import com.betcade.sdk.util.AuthUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class DBQRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    public DBQRequestInterceptor(){
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();
        if(<if necessary to send a token>){
            requestBuilder.addHeader(<TOKEN_HEADER_NAME>, <TOKEN>);
        }

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

**2.2)*** *(Also, optional step, only if you want to log request/response)*
Create logging interceptor:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor1 = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor1.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

**2.3)** Create HTTP client

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .writeTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)    // interceptor from step 2.1
        .addInterceptor(interceptor1)   // interceptor from step 2.2
        .build();
```

**2.4).** Create TrackResponse model:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TrackResponse {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public String getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

**2.5)** Create `interface ApiClient`:

```
public interface ApiClient {

    @GET("tracks/{id}")
    Observable<TrackResponse> getTrackInfo(@Path("id") String trackId);
}
```

**2.6).** Creat instance of `ApiClient`:

```
Retrofit API = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl("https://api.spotify.com/v1/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

ApiClient client = API.create(ApiClient.class);
```

**2.7).** Getting the name:

```
    client.getTrackInfo("5Q41NLTmGbVPozwHKK7bk2")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<TrackResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void call(TrackResponse trackResponse) {
                    String name = track.getName();
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```